# Slider won't work in IE8

Tags: css, html, slider, css3pie

I'm currently building a website but I noticed the slider doesn't work in IE8.  When I click on the compatibility mode button it does work.

It shows some strangely misplaced `div`s when I viewed in IE8. I recently built in Pie for the rounded corners to work in IE8; maybe that's the problem with the slider?

Is there anyone that can help me?

Here's the code :)

```
<div class="slider-container">
<div id="slideshow">
    <div>
        <div class="caption rc">
            <div class="caption-text">
                <?php perch_content('tekst slide 1'); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <img src="img/slider.jpg" alt="Slide">
    </div>
    <div>
    <div class="caption rc">
            <div class="caption-text">
                <?php perch_content('tekst slide 2'); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <img src="img/slider-2.jpg" alt="Slide">
    </div>
    <div>
    <div class="caption rc">
            <div class="caption-text">
                <?php perch_content('tekst slide 3'); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <img src="img/slider-3.jpg" alt="Slide">
    </div>
    <div>
    <div class="caption rc">
            <div class="caption-text">
                <?php perch_content('tekst slide 4'); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <img src="img/slider-4.jpg" alt="Slide">
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here:

```
$(function() {

    $("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

    setInterval(function() { 
      $('#slideshow > div:first')
        .fadeOut(1000)
        .next()
        .fadeIn(1000)
        .end()
        .appendTo('#slideshow');
    },  6000);

});
```

The strange thing is that it will work in compatibility mode, but not in normal mode, in IE8 and in Firefox, Chrome, and Safari it's working fine.

Comment: Is your jquery libary correct loaded? Do you use lokal libary or via cdn?

Comment: To be honest, I have absolutely no clue, not much of a js hero. This is the link to the page using the slider :) www.k2stuc.nl

Answer (score 0):

You are using a cdn, sometimes there is trouble loading cdn files... 
Try adding a fallback script to load jquery from your local server.
Add this after your jquery script from google cdn in the header and modify your path.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
    document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='path to jquery libary' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
}
</script>
```

Hope this helps

regards

Comment: But I have no js files on my server?

Comment: u have to add them manually to your server. You can get it from http://jquery.com/